# How to send current page number of jQuery Datatables to controller action method MVC C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am binding my data using Datatables. I have edit and delete button on every row. Clicking edit will navigate to edit view.

After saving the data in edit view, it is navigated to index view to the first page of the DataTable.

I want it to navigate to the updated row or atleast to the page where the updated row is in rather than going to the first page.

Please help me with this.

Comment: https://datatables.net/q/?q=current+page

Comment: Hi welcome to SO.  Please do take the [tour] and read the [ask] page (both linked from when you ask a question).   Before asking your question, make sure you have done at least [*some* research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) into a solution and *include* that research in your question.  For example how to get the current page from datatables as linked above should have been easy to find.

Comment: Specifically from the "ask a question" and [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) pages: *The community is here to help you with "**a specific programming problem**".*

Answer (score 0):

test with stateSave property of datatable

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    stateSave: true
 } );
```

Comment: Actually, stateSave was working for me, initially. I used  select2 for one of the columns to have multiple filter. I did this in initcomplete of Datatables. Then, stateSave stopped working.